# Joining two tables in SQL Server to remove entries that are not present in one of the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table A

```
  firstName       lastName       person_id Sale
  ..............................................
  ann             prasanth        2        102
  ann             prasanth        2         30
  sruthy          asr             1         23
```

and B

```
  firstName       lastName       person_id Sale
  ..............................................
  ann             prasanth        2         44
  pet             anther          3         99
  sruthy          asr             1         24
  sruthy          asr             1         61
```

I would like to get a table C where there are all the persons from table B that are also available in A. So pet anther would be removed since he is in table B but not in A.
The resulting table should look like this:

```
  firstName       lastName       person_id Sale
  ..............................................
  ann             prasanth        2         44
  sruthy          asr             1         24
  sruthy          asr             1         61
```

Comment: Looks like you got a normalization issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_b
WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM table_a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`

```
select * from TableB b
where exists 
            (
             select 1 from TableA a where a.person_id=b.person_id
            )
```

Or you can also use `in`

```
select * from TableB b
    where person_id in (select person_id from TableA )
```

I would suggest to use `exists`.

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table TableA (firstName varchar(50), lastName varchar(50), person_id int, Sale int);
 insert into TableA values('ann',      'prasanth',        2, 102);
 insert into TableA values('ann',      'prasanth',        2, 30);
 insert into TableA values('sruthy',   'asr',             1, 23);
 
 
 create table TableB(firstName varchar(50), lastName varchar(50), person_id int,  Sale int);
 insert into TableB values('ann',    'prasanth',        2,         44);
 insert into TableB values('pet',    'anther',          3,         99);
 insert into TableB values('sruthy', 'asr',             1,         24);
 insert into TableB values('sruthy', 'asr',             1,         61);
```

Query#1 (using exists)

```
 select * from TableB b
 where exists 
             (
              select 1 from TableA a where a.person_id=b.person_id
             )
```

Output:

| firstName | lastName | person_id | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | prasanth | 2 | 44 |
| sruthy | asr | 1 | 24 |
| sruthy | asr | 1 | 61 |

Query#2: (using in)

```
 select * from TableB b
     where person_id in (select person_id from TableA )
```

Output:

| firstName | lastName | person_id | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ann | prasanth | 2 | 44 |
| sruthy | asr | 1 | 24 |
| sruthy | asr | 1 | 61 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4023ce381d5d71ad7509c5898aae21f0)*

Answer (score 0):

BY the looks of it you simply need to use a join between the 2 tables or an EXIST condition.

Something like

```
SELECT ta.firstname, ta.lastname, ta.person_id, ta.Sale
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON tb.person_id = ta.person_id
;
```

The INNER JOIN basically ensures that only records that exist in both tables (based on the condition tb.person_id = ta.person_id) are returned.

Comment: This will generate wrong result. Please check the link: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41548c0ad9579af1467fcbca6a04bb17)*